# Is there any way to parameterise the table name provided in a SQL query in mule 4

Tags: database, mule4

I have tried the following queries - 
INSERT INTO (:tableName) (ENTITY_NAME,PAYLOAD_BLOB,PAYLOAD_JSON) VALUES (:entityName,:payload_blob,:payload_json);

INSERT INTO #vars.tableName (ENTITY_NAME,PAYLOAD_BLOB,PAYLOAD_JSON) VALUES (:entityName,:payload_blob,:payload_json);

INSERT INTO $(vars.tableName) (ENTITY_NAME,PAYLOAD_BLOB,PAYLOAD_JSON) VALUES (:entityName,:payload_blob,:payload_json);

But all the 3 queries resulted in an Bad Synatx error.

Answer (score 0):

Create variable with SQL statement

```
INSERT INTO ${vars.tableName} (ENTITY_NAME,PAYLOAD_BLOB,PAYLOAD_JSON) VALUES (:entityName,:payload_blob,:payload_json)
```

then use it in the Insert Component. Keep in mind - you still have to provide these internal values :entityName,:payload_blob,:payload_json in this Insert Component.